# Python Scapy not sniffing

Tags: python, scapy

When I run the script, `scapy` does not listen on the interface, it just print out this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "keylogger.py", line 91, in 
>       sniff_packets(scapy_expression, target_site)
>     File "keylogger.py", line 15, in sniff_packets
>       sniff(filter=scapy_expression, prn=sniffer_callback(target_site), store=0, iface="eth0")
>   TypeError: sniffer_callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

The code where the error occurs is the following (the expression that sniff)

```
def sniff_packets(scapy_expression, target_site):
    sniff(filter=scapy_expression, prn=sniffer_callback(target_site), store=0, iface="eth0")
```

This is the callback function:

```
    def sniffer_callback(packet, target_site):

            print "[*] Got a packet"
```

I am not sure why `scapy` doesn't listen to the wire. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this really more complicated than passing a second argument to `sniffer_callback(target_site)`?  I'm weary of any answer that seems so simple, but it looks like changing `prn=sniffer_callback(target_site)` to `prn=sniffer_callback` would actually work

Comment: Let me try this another way, it looks like you are passing the result of the function `sniffer_callback(target_site)` (which isn't working because you have defined `sniffer_callback()` to take 2 arguments instead of one), but the correct way to use this is to pass the function

Comment: yes but the sniffer_callback is automatically passed the packet as an arguement, so when its use prn=sniffer_callback(target_site) its getting passed target site and then the packet

Comment: plus the sniff function would work before it calls the sniffer function. It would error out once a packet was received

Comment: if `sniffer_callback(target_site)` returned a function then I would see how this could work, but as `sniffer_callback()` is defined it is going to return `None` (the default of any def where a return isn't present)

Comment: You can test this in the REPL.  First define a function with 2 arguments: `def sniffer_callback(a, b): print a+":"+b`, then try and associate it while only passing one: `prn = sniffer_callback('prn')`, you will see the same error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: `prn=sniffer_callback(target_site)`. You call `sniffer_callback` with one argument, which is wrong.

It should probably be: `prn=sniffer_callback`. Because it is a callback function, `sniffer_callback` should be called from somewhere inside function `sniff`. Therefor you give the function itself as an argument, not a value that it has computed.

Comment: @ Jason Sperske Yes, we have answered in parallel.